Are there exceptions to the upper - lower bound test for roots of polynomials?
For the polynomial $2x^4 + 27x^3 - 68x^2 - 333x + 180$
$4$ is a root of the polynomial and graphically is the greatest real root. I am finding $-3, -15$ and $0.5$ as additional roots. However, when using synthetic division the signs of the values in the quotient   $(2x^3 + 35x^2 + 72x - 45)$ are not all positive which is what I would expect according to my understanding of the theorem for upper bounds. Several web resources say all values in the bottom row must be positive, others note the coefficients in the bottom row must be positive. The coefficients $2, 35, 72$ are positive with $-45$ as the constant. Before this problem, I would have seen a negative in the bottom row and moved forward thinking there is a root greater than four. I am wondering what the actual theorem is and if the sign of the constant term is not to be considered.
Could someone shed light on the error of my work or understanding of this theorem?

for all positive roots  the coefficients  would have strictly alternating signs. What is $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) ; ; ? ; ; ; $

Please add to your question the statement of the theorem.

Define $x=y+4$ where  $y$ is the deviation of $x$ from $4$. Then
$2x^3+35x^2+72x-45=2y^3+59y^2+448y+931$
whose coefficients are all positive. So the polynomial is positive for all $x>4$.
